# Numpy array wrong dimensions with calculations

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have a matrix

```
import numpy as np 
A = np.array([[.7,.2,.1],[0,.6,.4],[.5,0,.5]]);A
```

I want to make a function that calculate a stationarity :

```
def statdist(A):
    m = A.shape[0]
    s = (m,m)
    I = np.identity(3)
    return( np.ones(m)@np.linalg.inv(I)- A+np.ones(s))


statdist(A)
```

The result must be

```
 0.4761905 0.2380952 0.2857143
```

but the output from python is a matrix:

```
array([[1.3, 1.8, 1.9],
       [2. , 1.4, 1.6],
       [1.5, 2. , 1.5]])
```

What I make wrong ?

In R is simple right :

```
statdist <- function(gamma){
  m = dim(gamma)[1]
  matrix(1,1,m) %*% solve(diag(1,m) - gamma + matrix(1,m,m))
}

i = matrix(c(.7,.2,.1,0,.6,.4,.5,0,.5),3,3,byrow = TRUE);i
statdist(i)
```

Comment: Check the dimensions of every element in the return statement. The first term is a 1d vector whose shape is `(3,)` , while the second one `- A+np.ones(s)` is a sum of two 3x3 matrices.

Comment: Parentheses in the return value seem to be misplaced. It should be `np.ones(m)@np.linalg.inv(I- A+np.ones(s))`

Comment: `np.ones(m).reshape((1,m)` is (3,1) but still the result is wrong

Comment: @bb1 you are right thanks mate I didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is (3,3)

```
m = A.shape[0]            # 3
s = (m,m)
I = np.identity(3)        # (3,3)
return( np.ones(m)@np.linalg.inv(I)- A+np.ones(s))
```

in the last line

```
(3,) @ (3,3) => (3,3)
(3,3) - (3,3) + (3,) => (3,3)
```

### oops

```
(3,) @ (3,3) => (3,)
(3,) - (3,3) + (3,3) => (3,3)
```

with the suggested change

```
np.ones(m)@np.linalg.inv(I- A+np.ones(s))
                         (3,3)-(3,3)+(3,3) => (3,3)
      (3,) @     (3,3)  => (3,)
```

With the numbers:

```
In [621]: A = np.array([[.7,.2,.1],[0,.6,.4],[.5,0,.5]])
In [622]: np.ones(3)@np.linalg.inv(np.eye(3)- A+np.ones((3,3)))
Out[622]: array([0.47619048, 0.23809524, 0.28571429])
```

Comment: See @bb1's post in the main comments.  The return has a misplaced parenthesis